# Nuxt 3.0.0 transition/animations not working

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I tried to use all animations and transitions technics, but it doesn't work in today's latest version of **Nuxt 3.0.0 and Nitro 1.0.0.**

But when I use older projects where is Nuxt `3.0.0-rc.12` it's working.

Is there any package that is removed from the latest version of Nuxt?

If I use older versions everything is working fine but `Nuxt /3.0.0-rc.13/3.0.0-rc.14/ 3.0.0` does not work...

In Chrome inspect element switching between routes there are no toggling CSS classes like enter, leave, etc like in `rc.12`.

Comment: How did you use it? If you use `<Transition>` component, it works, I've just checked it in Nuxt 3.0.0.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-rwqv9n?file=components/TransitionFade.vue

Comment: Hi, here is a short video of my simple example that transitions anyway doesn't work.
https://youtu.be/_f6GUkkI0yU
@AleksandrSavkin

Comment: It seems like an issue with nuxt/framework, I just check it they are working on it.
There is a different way to use it in Nuxt, see docs - https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/transitions#transitions . Maybe you could try it.

Comment: Thanks @AleksandrSavkin i found way to solve problem :)